# Update service variable with input form Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I want to update a variable that is inside a service in Angular.
I want to update the variable with the input form when i click the button.

This is Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DashService {
  input: number = 0; //Varible that need update
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  public getVar() {
    return this.input;
  }
  public insertData(data) {
    this.input = data
  }
}
```

This is the component

```
import { DashService } from './dash.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private service: DashService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(  this.service.getVar())
  }
}
```

This is the component Html

```
    <form (submit)="onSubmit(input)">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Age</label>
      <input type="numer" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="age" age="age">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and at least make it valid code. As it stands, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Stack Overflow didnt let me upload all the code firts. i think it is ok now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';



@Injectable()
export class DashService {
  input = new BehaviorSubject('test');; //Varible that need update
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getVar() {
    return this.input.asObservable();
  }
  public insertData(data) {
    this.input.next(data);
  }
}
```

component

```
export class AppComponent {
    public age = '';
    constructor(public service: DashService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getVar().subscribe((data) => {
     console.log(data);
   } )
  }

  onSubmit() {
     this.service.insertData(this.age);
  }
}
```

html

```
    <form (submit)="onSubmit()">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Age</label>
      <input type="numer" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="age" age="age">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This change the value of variable in service but does not change the consle log output inside ngOnIt() . because i think it is called only once at firts. How to make it call every time that service variable change ?

Comment: @abc You need to use subjects and subscribe to it so that change is detected every time.

Comment: Any example or tutorial you can suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your issue due to less information in your code so try to use this link which I think the best way for you to transfer your data through a EventEmitter using cross component communication:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

or you just can use Subject from rxjs as observer and an Observable:

http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

Comment: I want to console log the value of the service variable inside the ngOnInit().  I want to do this every time the variable change from input value. I think i am more clear now.